# Search through line for a string and print that line only once to another file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a text file that has unique lines by timestamps. This below is the example of the lines in that text file:

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 08:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe1** Windows...

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 09:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe2** Windows...

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 09:30:34 2017: abc\**john.doe2** Windows...

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 10:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe3** Windows...

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 11:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe1** Windows...

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 12:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe3** Windows...

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 13:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe3** Windows...

...

These lines go a long way. I need to move the line where the first occurrence of **john.doe1** happened to another text file, and ignore every other line that has john.doe1 in it. I have to do the same for the whole file, that has many, many **john.does**.

My output to another file should look like this:

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 08:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe1** Windows...

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 09:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe2** Windows...

111.111.11.11: Jun 18 10:01:34 2017: abc\**john.doe3** Windows...

Problem is **john.does** are usually real names, and I do not know them before, I just know that they appear between the characters '\' and ' '.

Answer (score 4):

Extension of the familiar Awk de-duplication idiom to use a matched substring instead of a delimited field:

```
awk 'match($0, /\\[^ ]*/) && !seen[substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)]++' file
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!